# How do I allow a user to remove an uploaded asset from a front-end entry form?

Tags: assets, entry, entry-form

I see for users, I can add a hidden field `<input type="hidden" name="deleteUserPhoto" value="1" />` to remove the uploaded photo, however I need to allow this functionality for an assets field in an entry form.

I have tried submitting an empty file field, but it just retains the existing uploaded asset after submission.

Is there a trigger similar to `deleteUserPhoto` that I can use here?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

File fields are used for uploading new images. To delete all the Assets for a field, submit a hidden field with no values.

```
<input type="hidden" name="fields[assetsField]" value="" />
```

If, on the other hand, you want to retain some of them, then make that hidden field an array with the values you'd like to keep. Like this

```
<input type="hidden" name="fields[assetsField][]" value="someAssetId" />
<input type="hidden" name="fields[assetsField][]" value="someOtherAssetId" />
```

`someAssetId` and `someOtherAssetId` being the Asset IDs you'd like to keep for that field.

Comment: Thank you SO much :)